# Laravel - changing object attribute field that is inside of the #appends array

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to change the attributes of an object that I am returning as a json response from the function. I am not trying to save it and persist it to DB, only change it before I send it as an api response. This is the piece of code where I do that:

```
if ($item->post_title == '') {
     $post = $this->findPostId($item);
     $item->post_title = $post->post_title;
     $item->url = $post->guid;
     $item->slug = $post->slug;
     $item->setAttribute('post_id', $post->ID);
}
```

What I don't understand is why am I able to change the `post_title` attribute and set the attribute `post_id`, but not able to change the `url` and `slug` attributes. I have checked both `post->guid` and `post->slug` attributes and I get values for both of them, but the `item` object properties are not changed?

**Update**

Just realised that the `slug` field is inside of the `#appends` array of the model, and not in the `#attributes` array. Is there a way to change it for the given object?

Comment: Is it possible they’re _guarded_ attributes?

Comment: I haven't set anything in the laravel, but I am getting data from a WP database, and on expecting the object with ```dd($item)```  I see that it has  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]

Comment: can you post all your model properties?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 2):

Add fields to be fillable:

```
protected $fillable = ['url', 'slug']
```

Then you can do:

```
$item->update(["post_title" => $post->post_title,
               "url" => $post->guid
               // etc...
]);
```

Or this way:

```
$item->post_title = $post->post_title;
$item->url = $post->guis;
$item->save();
```

Comment: I am not trying to save it to the DB, I am just trying to change it before sending it as a response